# Unsure how to use nth selector in CSS grid because it seems to change all the elements whenever i add something to it

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

Whenever I use `:nth-child(1)` for just selecting one element it seems to select all of the elements. Whatever rules I create apply to all the elements, not just the first child.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.grid :nth-child(1){
    font-weight: bold;
}

.grid :nth-child(2){
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am rather new to CSS and Flexbox.

I was hoping it would only affect the first element.

Comment: Could you also provide your HTML code? It may because of the nested elements. Try `.grid > :nth-child(1)` to see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Let’s consider the meaning of these three slightly different selectors. (I’m using `:first-child`, but it does the same thing as `:nth-child(1)`.)

1. `.fred:first-child`
2. `.fred :first-child`
3. `.fred>:first-child`

The first one matches an element with a class of `.fred` which is (itself) the first child of its parent.

The second one matches any descendant of an element with a class of `.fred` which is the first child of its parent.

The third one matches only the first child of an element with a class of `.fred`.

You are using the equivalent of the second selector, but possibly ought to be using the equivalent of the third selector. But unless you include your HTML in your question, I can’t know for sure.